# benchmarking results between Titan and GTX690

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, gpu, hpc

I came across this benchmark comparison ( http://compubench.com/compare.jsp?config_0=14470292&config_1=18133965 ) between GTX-Titan and Tesla K40c, and the results seems very odd.Can someone please explain any possible reason behind this. How much would Tesla differ in performance if only single precision operations are being performed?

Comment: That comparisons are not "overclock-free" so any titan overclocker would surpass that expensive tesla. Also, firmware/drivers are different between professional and desktop versions so optimizations are different too! Even my overclocked HD7870 surpasses that tesla because Nvidia GPUs are not as optimized as AMD GPUs for opencl. They are for CUDA.  CUDA vs Opencl, cuda can win by %20-%50 on same Nvidia card with medium level optimizations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd opt for the Titan because it has more up-to-date instruction set capabilities. The GK110 ASIC that it is based on has SM 3.5 capability (e.g. read-through-texture, funnel shift) and also supports dynamic parallelism.

Maxwell is coming soon, but it will support more capabilities, not fewer, so you should use the GK110 as a baseline.